# value is not recorded in the database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

please help to find the error

model:

```
class Diary(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(
        '',
        blank=True,
        null=True,      
    )       
    title = models.CharField(
        'Заголовок записи',
        max_length=100, 
        blank=False,
    )                                   
    text = models.TextField(
        'Содержание записи',
        max_length=100, 
        blank=False,
    )
```

form:

```
class addMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Diary
        fields = (
            'title',  
            'text',
        )
```

view:

```
def add_records(request):   
    form = addMessageForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addMessageForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print('valid')
            Diary.save(
                user_id=request.user.pk, 
                title='sdffds', 
                text='324', 
            )

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/my_records/')

    t = loader.get_template('page_add_records.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form,
    }, [custom_proc])   

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

as a result of the browser displays the following error message:

> TypeError at /add_records/ save() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'user_id'

I do not understand why I'm doing a normal entry in the database and I have a bug related to the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not doing a "normal entry in the database". You are calling the `save` method directly from the class, which is not how you create and save an instance. You presumably meant to use `Diary.objects.create(...)` instead.

However none of this has anything to do with saving the form, which you would do by just calling `form.save()`.